# Suppress a Static file missing ValueError

Tags: python, django

I currently have a Django site and in one particular view, an image is displayed based on user input. With WhiteNoise, Django will report a 500 error if that image doesn't exist. However I would just rather serve a broken image reference than kill the whole page.

Is there a way to suppress the error in some cases? Or perhaps some views? The error looks like this:

`Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '291.png'`

I assume you'd need to use a middleware but I'm not 100% sure how.

Thanks

Comment: add your view to the question

Comment: It's not specific to the view @mohammedqudah in order to help other people that might have the issue I'm trying to make it generic. The view example was just to help you understand an example case why this would be needed.

Comment: do you know the python try block?

Comment: I do @mohammedqudah just not how to create a middleware to catch the error since this happens on the template.

Comment: are you using Ajax, or how you display the photo in the same template

Comment: I don't think you are understanding? There is no use of Ajax, just a Template.html being rendered. You'd call the static file with something like how it is shown here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Comment: so the form template is not the same display template, your question is not clear at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159296/discussion-between-mohammed-qudah-and-chaos).